# python try except as a function to evaluate expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I have tried creating a function that tries an expression and returns zero if errors are risen.

```
def try_or_zero(exp):
    try:
        exp
        return exp
    except:
        return 0
```

Which obviously doesn't work. It seems the problem is that python doesn't have any form of lazy evaluation, so the expression is evaluated before it's passed to the function and so it rises the error before it gets into the function and therefor it never passes through the try logic. 
Does anyone know if this can be done in Python?
Cheers

Comment: What exactly is being passed to try_or_zero?

Comment: you can pass it as a string and then use `eval()`

Comment: if you want to know about the error occurs use `logging`

Comment: do NOT use  `eval` - at least until you _fully_ understand why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: "Does anyone know if this can be done in Python" => yes, just pass a lambda to your function and call it from within the function, cf my answer.

Comment: I really don't understand the close votes here - the question is perfectly on topic and quite clear, and contains all needed informations to be answered.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems the problem is that python doesn't have any form of lazy evaluation

Err... yes it does, but possibly not in the form you expect. Function arguments ARE indeed eval'd before being passed to the function, so

```
try_or_zero(foo.bar())
```

will indeed be executed as:

```
param = foo.bar()
try_or_zero(param)
```

Now python functions are plain objects (they can be used as variables, passed around as arguments to functions etc), and they are only invoked when applying the call operator (the parens, with or without arguments) so you can pass a function to `try_or_zero` and let `try_or_zero` call the function:

```
def try_or_zero(func):
    try:
        return func()
    except Exception as e:
        return 0
```

Now you're going to object that 1/ this will not work if the function expects arguments and 2/ having to write a function just for this is a PITA - and both objections are valid. Hopefully, Python also has a shortcut to create simple anonymous functions consisting of a single (even if arbitrarily complex) expression: `lambda`. Also, python functions (including "lambda functions" - which are, technically, plain functions) are closure - they capture the context in which they're defined - so it's quite easy to wrap all this together:

```
a = 42
b = "c"

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

result = try_or_zero(lambda: add(a, b))
```

A side note about exception handling:

First don't use a bare except, at least catch `Exception` (else you might prevent some exception - like `SysExit`- to work as expected).

Also preferably only catch the exact exceptions you expect at a given point. In your case, you may want to pass a tuple of exceptions that you want to ignore, ie:

```
def try_or_zero(func, *exceptions):
    if not exceptions:
        exceptions = (Exception,)  
    try:
        return func()
    except exceptions as e:
        return 0


a = 42
b = "c"

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

result = try_or_zero(lambda: add(a, b), TypeError))
```

which will prevent your code from masking unexpected errors.

And finally: you may also want to add support for a return value other than zero in the case of an exception (not all expressions are supposed to return an int ):

```
# XXX : python3 only, python2 doesn't accept
# keyword args after *args

def try_or(func, *exceptions, default=0):
    if not exceptions:
        exceptions = (Exception,)  
    try:
        return func()
    except exceptions as e:
        return default

# adding lists is legit too,
# so here you may want an empty list as the return value
# instead
a = [1, 2, 3]
# but only to lists
b = ""

result = try_or(lambda: a + b, TypeError, default=[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to bother with `exec` and stuff, use the fact that python functions are objects and thus can be passed as arguments

```
def try_or_zero(exp):
    try:
       return exp()
    except:
       return 0
```

And just call `try_or_zero(my_awesome_func)` (without the () for your method)

Answer (score -2):

Pass the argument to function in str and do the exec inside function

```
def try_or_zero(exp):
    try:
        exec(exp)
        return exp
    except:
        return 0
```

so your call to function will be like below 
try_or_zero('1==2')

Comment: Please don't. `exec` and `eval` are almost always the wrong solutions.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by enveloping your expressions in a function.
For example:

```
def ErrorTest():
    # the expression you want to try
    raise Exception
```

Also your try function should look like this:

```
 def try_catch(exp):
    try :
        exp()  # note the paranthesis
    except:
        return 0
```

And put it inside the function

```
try_or_zero(ErrorTest)

OutPut: 0
```

You Can also do it by using the eval() function, but you will have to put your code in String.

```
try_or_zero(exp):
    try:
        eval(exp)  # exp must be a string, for example 'raise ValueError'
    except:
        return 0
```

Comment: please do not advocate using `eval`.

Comment: Can you explain why? Is that a deprecated method? Or is there a much preferable way? Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Issues with  `eval` (and `exec`) have already been explained in depth in various places. Mostly: those "features" are dangerous (they run just any arbitrary code), hard to debug (you don't have a proper traceback and cannot step thru), and force you to pass code as string, which means this code cannot be linted nor instrumentalized in any way.  The point is: 99.999% of what `eval` do can be done in documented, pythonic, safer, readable and maintainable way (using a lambda, using `getattr` / `setattr`, using the `ast` package, using `inspect` etc).